# ansible playbook, different user by operating system

Tags: ansible

I'm starting to play with [ansible](http://ansible.cc/). I have a bunch of servers (Ubuntu, Centos, Red hat...).

The servers have different users. For the ubuntu servers I use sudo user, for the rest I use root user.

How could I specify the user by operating system?

Comment: You really should get into the habit of using `sudo` across all your servers, even if it isn't the default for Red Hat systems. It's best practice to do so for security and audit purposes.

Comment: yes, it is the goal. I'm trying unify the sudo user for all servers with an playbook. But I have two groups of servers (Ubuntu and Red Hat systems). The first group authenticate whit a sudo and the second with  root. I'm following this [article](http://lextoumbourou.com/blog/posts/getting-started-with-ansible/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#operating-system-and-distribution-variance) mention performing tasks just for particular operating systems. You could tweak this to set the user for each OS. For example

```
- hosts: CentOS
  user: centos
  tasks:
  - # some tasks

- hosts: Debian
  user: default
  - # some tasks

- hosts: Ubuntu
  user: ubuntu
  - # some tasks
```

In the source, it appears that these operating systems are supported, though I could not confirm this in the official documentation at the time of this writing.

- RedHat
- Fedora
- CentOS
- Scientific
- SLC
- Ascendos
- CloudLinux
- PSBM
- OracleLinux
- OVS
- OEL
- Amazon
- XenServer
- Ubuntu
- Debian
- SLES
- SLED
- OpenSuSE
- SuSE
- Gentoo
- ArchLinux
- Mandriva
- Mandrake
- Solaris
- Nexenta
- OmniOS
- OpenIndiana
- SmartOS

You can also have per-OS variables defined in `vars/<os-name>.yaml` files and conditionally use them using the `ansible_os_family` template variable as shown [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docsite/latest/rst/playbooks2.rst#conditional-imports).

Comment: Ok, I think that it will solve the problem.

Comment: Do you know what osx is?

Comment: This does not work for us with `ansible 2.2.1.0`. Our workaround: Use `hosts: '*'` and use conditionals in the role.

Answer (score 3):

The CentOS and so on isn't automatic. It's a group over ansible provided variable. Here is a full example, dealing with CentOS plus VM or not VM.

```
---
- name: RG Ansible for ALL
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: group by OS versions
    group_by: key="{{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_version.split('.')[0] }}"
  - name: group by physical/virtual machine
    group_by: key="{{ ansible_virtualization_role }}"
...
- name: RG Ansible for CentOS 6
  hosts: CentOS_6
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
...
- name: RG Ansible for CentOS 5
  hosts: CentOS_5
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

- name: RG Ansible for VM
  hosts: guest
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - service: name=acpid state=stopped enabled=no
  - service: name=cpuspeed state=stopped enabled=no
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the user on the [command line](http://ansible.cc/docs/playbooks2.html):

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml --extra-vars "user=bar"

-----
- user: '{{ user }}'
```

Specify a different `user` [per host-group](http://ansible.cc/docs/patterns.html) in `/etc/ansible/hosts`

```
[targets]

localhost              ansible_connection=local
other1.example.com     ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_ssh_user=mpdehaan
other2.example.com     ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_ssh_user=mdehaan
```

Comment: you specify the user by host. But I need specify the user by operating system. I think that a solution is specify the operating system on __/etc/ansible/hosts__ variables. It is like your solution